# ios 7 UIBarButtonItem UIAppearance not setting font

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm using this piece of code to set the default font (Custom) for all my UIBarButtonItems:

```
NSDictionary *attributesBarButtonItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Light" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributesBarButtonItem forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSLog(@"%@", [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
```

However, it seems to be ignored as the font does not change, and NSLog returns (null). It's a bit confusing because its pretty much the same code I'm using to set the default font for all my navigation bars and it works fine for them.

The piece of code is placed in AppDelegate´s didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but I've also test it in other viewControllers (viewDidLoad) with exact same result.

Other strange behaviour I've noticed:
I've got a tab bar controller, and when I load any viewController with bar button items it doesn't work, but if I push another viewController it works (The font is changed to the selected one), and it keeps working even if that viewController is popped out, although it will stop working if another tab is pushed.

Any help to try to set a default font for the UIBarButtonItems would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is this font coming from? I'm not sure i've ever heard of it

Comment: It's a custom font (If you mean that you haven't seen it in the fonts that the SDK provides), but I don't think thats the problem since I've use it on some UILabels and the navigation bar and there isn't any problem

Comment: Still having that issue with iOS 10... Is that just a bug flying under the radar? Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Biniou Yeah they fixed after a couple of updates and I haven't experienced the issue ever again

Answer (score 2):

Is this your custom font ?

There could be few problems:

- is the font in TTF format ?
- if you click on the font in xcode is Target membership in right panel checked ?
- did you add the font to project plist file ?
  [image]

Also you should use **UITextAttributeFont** in the dictionary:

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Light" size:18.0]} [forState:forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: There are no problems with the custom font, as I stated, its already working in the navigation bar and other labels(It doesn't even work using Helvetica Neue, for example). Also, UITextAttributeFont is deprecated in ios 7 (I've also tried compiling the project for ios 6 with UITextAttributeFont and it doesnt work either).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue arise because I was creating the `leftBarButtonItem` before I set the appearance attributes.  Swapping the order such that appearance was set first fixed the problem.

Comment: I had to put this in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` instead of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in my app delegate.